# Correct way of using .ToLookup() with an EF Core query

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to use the `.ToLookup()` method with an EF Core query and wondering what the best practice is when using it, should I be buffering the query into a list first, or call `.ToLookup()` directly on the `IQueryable`?

```cs
var lookup = DbContext.Foo.Where(f => f.Id > 1).ToLookup(f => f.Id);

//vs:

var lookup = (await DbContext.Foo.Where(f => f.Id > 1).ToListAsync(cancellation)).ToLookup(f => f.Id);
```

My main concern is the `ToListAsync` approach will execute the query asynchronously whereas the direct `.ToLookup` call *looks* like it will block until results of the query are returned.

However as @Tim mentioned the `ToListAsync` approach will end up creating 2 collections in memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup?view=net-7.0) creates an in-memory collection similar to a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, so there is no need to create a list and then call `ToLookup`, you will just waste CPU and memory for no reason.

So it's similar to `ToDictionary`, but different to [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=net-7.0). The latter is using "deferred execution", which means you are still in a database context when you consume it, whereas the lookup or dictionary are collections that are already filled.